# Redirect from page without parameters to page with parameters in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, parameters

I need to redirect from page like this www.site.ru/machines/ to page www.site.ru/machines/?set_filter=y&PRICE_MIN=4500 in the mod_rewrite section of .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(machines/)$ /$1?set_filter=y&PRICE_MIN=4500 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: I tried this rule but browser redirected to this page http://www.site.ru/var/www/user/data/www/site/?set_filter=y&PRICE_MIN=4500

Comment: now it's added 'machines' inside this path  /www/site/machines/?set_filter...http://www.site.ru/var/www/user/data/www/site/machines/?set_filter=y&PRICE_MIN=4500

Comment: sorry i've forgotten slash. Thank you much for your adviсe. It works now.